# DebugBreak() causes Win7 x64 to hang on one specific machine? Possible setting problem?

Tags: debugging, windows-7, crash, 64-bit

We're using DebugBreak() and/or asm int 3 as a method to stop our unit test framework when an assertion happens.  The unit test framework runs as a user mode application.

We're running win 7 x64, enterprise edition, and generally using vs2008, but also Windbg.  Usually, when the DebugBreak is called, the "check for solutions/close/debug" dialog pops up.

On one user's machine (Dell T5500, 8 cores, 12GB) the DebugBreak call causes the whole machine to stop.  The clock widget stops ticking, mouse stops moving, keyboard stops responding.  The dialog does not pop-up, even though we've checked that it is configured to.  We need to force shutdown the machine to do anything further.

Is anyone aware of any kind of windbg or other JIT debug option that might cause this?  This user has guessed that his machine might be acting like its set up for remote debugging, but this isn't a kernel breakpoin.  We often use remote debugging but the machine that is hanging is usually the debugger, not the debugee.

Comment: if the purpose is only to stop your unit testing user mode application, then DebugBreak() might not be the best choice - why not just simply stop it by other means - you can gracefully close the application or display message box if you want some user interaction. The problem is interesting, anyways, it would be more informative if you could describe the callstack of the hung thread. You might also want to play with setting a default JIT debugger to see if it chnges anything, e.g. `windbg -I`

Comment: The program is in unmanaged C/C++.  We use the DebugBreak because when a test fails, most of the time the developer would like to debug the problem right there, so entering the debugger directly is beneficial.  The tests also generally are too complicated, so debugging on the first failure occurrence is often desirable to rerunning and hoping it happens again.
There is no callstack, the machine hangs completely on the DebugBreak.  I will suggest he set configure windbg like that.

Answer (score 2):

So, after reconsidering and re-investigating, it turns out the developer **had** enabled the debugger on his development system a long time ago, so the DebugBreak was actually stopping the kernel.  From his machine:

`C:\>bcdedit`

`Windows Boot Manager

--------------------`
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
timeout                 30

resumeobject            {fdc7f9bc-32c9-11df-8189-b982443308cd}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
`Windows Boot Loader

-------------------`
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {fdc7f9c0-32c9-11df-8189-b982443308cd}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {fdc7f9bc-32c9-11df-8189-b982443308cd}
nx                      OptIn
**debug                   Yes**

Disabling that made everything work correctly.  Thanks for your time.